# Get world Vertex Position of a TriMesh - 3ds Max SDK C#

Tags: c#, c++, 3d, transform, 3dsmax

Currently I'm writing a plugin for my company and we want to offset some math operations on meshes to C# to gain some speed in calculations. I'm not only a C# beginner (I'm a Python / Maxscript guy) but I also struggle to find good SDK documentation for 3DS Max.

My current problem: obtaining the world-relative position of a vertex in a mesh. Sounds easy but it poses some problems for me. I can get the vert position by using:

```
IPoint3 x = mesh.GetVert(vertID);
```

and for vert 3 which is in [0,0,0] of the scene it returns a Point3 value of [-23,86499, 17,5783, 0], probably relative to... well, center of the object I think. Or some local transformation matrix. The thing I want to get is the position of the vert in world space, which in  this case I know is [0,0,0], as well as I can probe it with MaxScript by using:

```
polyOp.getVert $ 3
```

The simple function I'm using to poke around is:

```
List<IINode> nodes = nodesFromHandles(objHandles);
foreach (IINode i in nodes)
{
    log(i.Name);
    IObjectState iState = i.EvalWorldState(0, true);
    IObject iObj = iState.Obj;
    IPolyObject iPoly = (IPolyObject)iObj.ConvertToType(0, global.PolyObjectClassID);
    ITriObject iTri = (ITriObject)iObj.ConvertToType(0, global.TriObjectClassID);
    IMesh mesh = iTri.Mesh;
    for (int vertID = 0; vertID < mesh.NumVerts; vertID++)
    {
        IPoint3 x = mesh.GetVert(vertID); /// RETURNS A BAD POSITION? RELATIVE TO WHAT MATRIX?
        log(vertID.ToString() + ": " + x.X.ToString() + ", " + x.Y.ToString() + ", " + x.Z.ToString());
    }
}
```

I guess I should probably do *something* with the object transform matrix, but I'm in the dark with that. Working on: 3ds Max 2014, MS visual Studio Community 2015 (C#), Win7x64, using Autodesk.Max.DLL. Any and all help appreciated, thank you in advance!

[image: Expected vertex position.]

EDIT: (solution?)
Correct me if I'm wrong, but by doing some satanic rituals and sacrificing some of my teeth I've come up with this thing. I essentially grab the object world Transform Matrix at a given time (set to frame 0, because why not?) and then doing a point transform. Seems to work quite well for now, but I need to do more tests.

```
List<IINode> nodes = nodesFromHandles(objHandles);
foreach (IINode i in nodes)
{
    log(i.Name);
    IObjectState iState = i.EvalWorldState(0, true);
    IObject iObj = iState.Obj;
    ITriObject iTri = (ITriObject)iObj.ConvertToType(0, global.TriObjectClassID);
    IMesh mesh = iTri.Mesh;

    /// OBJECT TRANSFORM MATRIX
    IInterval iTimeRange = i.GetTimeRange(0);
    IMatrix3 worldTm = i.GetObjTMAfterWSM(0, iTimeRange);

    for (int vertID = 0; vertID < mesh.NumVerts; vertID++)
    {
        IPoint3 x = mesh.GetVert(vertID); /// RETURNS A BAD POSITION? RELATIVE TO WHAT MATRIX?
        IPoint3 v = worldTm.PointTransform(x);
        log(vertID.ToString() + ": " + v.X.ToString() + ", " + v.Y.ToString() + ", " + v.Z.ToString());
    }
}
```

If anybody can verify or improve this - your welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding some explanations to your answer. The following line:

```
IPoint3 vertObjectSpace = mesh.GetVert(vertID);
```

Returns the vertex position in **object** space, which is unfortunately not mentioned in the docs. As you are interested in the positions in **world** space, you have to transform them using the following:

```
IMatrix3 tmObj2World= i.GetObjectTM(0, iTimeRange); // where i is your IINode
IPoint3 vertWorldSpace = tmObj2World.PointTransform(vertObjectSpace);
```

Hope that helps for your understanding.

Some notes / further reading:

- Docs about `GetObjectTM` and `GetObjTMAfterWSM` (guess I would prefer to use `GetObjectTM`, unless you explicitly have to use `GetObjTMAfterWSM`):
  [image: doc GetObjectTM]
  [image: doc GetObjTMAfterWSM]
- 3ds max uses the following three spaces: world, node/local and object. For some background info, see: http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_3B001F21_8FE9_4663_A972_E648682A0ACD_htm
- The node transform (unfortunately not the object transform) can be visualized in 3ds max with the following
  [image: view local/node tm in 3ds max]